# How do I have a function run every time a user visits my Django application?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a function that checks whether a late payment fee should be charged to users who pay late in my Django application. Since I cannot write a cron job, I must run this function every time a user visits my application.

I could just call this function at the beginning of every view in my application, but that would be repeating the function name a lot.

How do I have a function run every time a user visits my Django application? Should I perhaps call the function in settings.py?

Comment: "Since I cannot write a cron job" - why not?

Comment: I have a shared hosting account on Dreamhost. I don't think I have the admin privilege to make a cron job programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own middleware and add it to the list of middlewares in your settings. The middleware itself is just a class with some functions that act as hooks to certain points in the processing chain for a request:

```
class MyMiddleware (request):

    process_request(self,request):
       # do something here before passing the request to the view

    process_response(self,request,response):
       # do something here before passing the response to the client
```

There are some other hooks available to specify the exact point where your funcion kicks in, you best look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) to see what's best for your case.

In the settings just add your middleware to the middleware classes:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'your_app.middleware.MyMiddleware',
```

)

That should do exactly what you want.